# Android drawable resources issue

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources, android-drawable

I've noticed that real device picks up different resource from that eclipse shows in preview.
For example I created drawable resources for devices with smallest width of 720dp as

- `drawable-sw720dp-mdpi` for Samsung Galaxy Tab 1280x800 mdpi
- `drawable-sw720dp-hdpi` for Nexus 10 2560x1600 hdpi.

But *Samsung Galaxy Tab 1280x800 mdpi* picks up the `drawable-sw720dp-hdpi` instead of `drawable-sw720dp-mdpi` ?

Same thing with other devices. If there are resources `drawable-sw320dp-hdpi`, `drawable-sw320dp-xhdpi`, the *Sony Ericsson xperia-ARC 854x480 hdpi* picks up `drawable-sw320dp-xhdpi` ?

I cant just keep `drawable-hdpi` resource because there are devices 5'5 inch screen size. For example samsung galaxy 1280x720 hdpi 5'5 inch, and for such devices there is different graphical design so both devices 854x480 hdpi and 1280x720 hdpi will be using the same directory `drawable-hdpi wich` is not acceptable.

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried to create these drawable folders in a sample project and change different devices in graphic layout of eclipse, the appearance is just correct, devices pick the right drawable.

Comment: Yes in Eclipse graphic layout picks up right drawable. But real device picks different! I put picture with text "sw720dp-mdpi" in drawable-sw720dp-mdpi, and another one with text "sw720dp-hdpi" in drawable-sw720dp-hdpi. Device 10' inch 1280x800 mdpi showed me picture with text "sw720dp-hdpi" but DisplayMetrics returned to me density value of 160 (mdpi). That is surprised me.

Comment: How calculate 720 value of drawable-sw720dp for 2560*1600 resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had similar problem, while writing animated wallpaper which was using canvas and bitmaps. I couldn't achieve what I wanted using default layout folders.

In my case, for example, medium density device with xlarge screen (1280x800), should use the same resources as high density with normal screen (600x1024).

I've decided to write my own solution, by putting resources into three groups and selecting them using custom rules.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
int screenSize = resources.getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

switch (metrics.densityDpi) {
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL || screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
        return new SmallResourceProvider(resources);
    }
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
        return new MediumResourceProvider(resources);
    }
default:
    return new LargeResourceProvider(resources);
}
```

Maybe this will be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same strange issue. In my case Galaxy tab GT P7500 was picking images from drawable-sw720dp-XXHDPI folder as i had the XXHDPI folder also. If i deleted the XXHDPI, it picks up the next lower which is the XHDPI folder.

The issue is with the swxxxdp qualifier for drawable folders. If i remove the screen width and use just 1 set of images of all densities the issue seems to be resolved. However i wanted to have different set of drawables for 7 inch and 10 inch devices. What i did was use a different set of names for the 10 inch images and 7 inch images and use 2 different set of layouts with sw600dp and sw720dp qualifiers.
Here is my current structure which works well. However this is not the expected way of using the resources, as android recommends [externalizing the drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html). unfortunately i couldn't find a better solution.

```
layout-land
layout-sw600dp-land (uses image.png)
layout-sw720dp-land (image_large.png)
```

and for drawables,

```
drawble-mdpi (image.png & image_large.png)
drawable-hdpi 
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
```